# c++ variadic template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, trailing-return-type

I am using c++11 variadic template, however the compiler complains template instantiation depth excedds maximun of 900, the code looks like:

```
template<typename F1, typename F2>
composed<F1, F2> compose(F1 f1, F2 f2) {
    return composed<F1, F2>(f1, f2);
}
template<typename F1, typename F2, typename... Fs>
auto compose(F1 f1, F2 f2, Fs... fs) ->decltype(compose(compose(f1, f2), fs...)) {
    return compose(compose(f1, f2), fs...);
}
```

I am using this template like:

```
auto composed_func = compose(f1, f2, f3, f4);
```

But if I change the variadic template defination to:

```
template<typename F1, typename F2, typename F3, typename... Fs>
auto compose(F1 f1, F2 f2, F3 f3, Fs... fs) ->decltype(compose(compose(f1, f2), f3, fs...)) {
    return compose(compose(f1, f2), f3, fs...);
}
```

It will work OK.
I am not clear why this happened. It seems to me that the upper usage also looks valid since it still recursively reduce the args to call compose.

Comment: The type pack can be empty. Which overload will it end up in?

Comment: Having the third parameter before the type pack disambiguates between the two functions for the case of two parameters.

Comment: @KhouriGiordano thanks for your reply, i once wrote code like this, and it worked  template<typename T>
std::ostream & simple_logger::print(const T& t) {
    return _os << t << std::endl;
}

template<typename T, typename ... args>
std::ostream & simple_logger::print(const T& t, const args &... rest) {
    _os << t << ", ";
    return print(rest...);
}

Comment: @KhouriGiordano sorry for the format of code in comment, it looks ugly... but it really worked, one template takes only one T, while another template takes one T and a ...args

Comment: @D.pz: For thing like `some code`, you might format with backquote ` around the code.

Comment: @KhouriGiordano thx, i finally understood your explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might fix it with:

```
template<typename F1, typename F2>
composed<F1, F2> compose(F1 f1, F2 f2) {
    return composed<F1, F2>(f1, f2);
}

template<typename F1, typename F2, typename... Fs>
auto compose(F1 f1, F2 f2, Fs... fs)
->decltype(compose(::compose(f1, f2), fs...))
{
    return compose(compose(f1, f2), fs...);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe3eedb3a1d115a5)

Unqualified names can be found by ADL and name is search at the point of instantiation.

so, with unqualified look up, we first generated the candidates (even if they won't be the better match)

`compose(f, g)` can be:

- `template<typename F1, typename F2> compose`
- or `template<typename F1, typename F2, typename...Fs> compose`. (with `FS` empty pack)

for the later case, we have `decltype(compose(compose(f, g)))` to resolve, and so `compose(f, g)` again -> infinite recursion.

On the other part, qualified names is search immediately, and only fully declared functions can be found (so not itself, as the trailing-return-type is part of the declaration).
so `::compose` avoid to consider itself as candidate of overloads.

Comment: it really worked, and your explanation is very clear, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You have infinite recursion in your second function: it does not call the first function, as you may have thought, but calls itself instead:

```
template<typename F1, typename F2, typename... Fs>
auto compose(F1 f1, F2 f2, Fs... fs) ->decltype(compose(compose(f1, f2), fs...)) {
    return compose(compose(f1, f2), fs...);
}
```

Let's say you call:

```
compose(f, g, h);
```

This invokes the function with `F1 = decltype(f)`, `F2 = decltype(g)`, and `Fs = {decltype(h)}`. The function then goes on and invokes:

```
compose(f1, f2)
```

which is actually:

```
compose(f, g);
```

This invokes the same function with  `F1 = decltype(f)`, `F2 = decltype(g)`, and an empty `Fs = {}`. Basically executing:

```
compose(compose(f, g));
```

Which again calls itself with `F1 = decltype(f)`, `F2 = decltype(g)`, and an empty `Fs = {}`. And this goes on to infinity, or until the limit of 900 is reached.

What you need is to make sure that the second function is relevant only when there is something after `f2`:

```
template<typename F1, typename F2, typename F3, typename... Fs>
auto compose(F1 f1, F2 f2, F3 f3, Fs... fs) ->decltype(compose(compose(f1, f2), f3, fs...)) {
    return compose(compose(f1, f2), f3, fs...);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, it is a very very clear explanation